# Can't achieve 60fps rendering simple quad, Android, Opengl ES 2.0

Tags: android, optimization, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on a simple pong type game to get to grips with opengl and android, and seem to have hit a brick wall in terms of performance.

I've got my game logic on a separate thread, with draw commands sent to the gl thread through a blocking queue. The problem is that I'm stuck at around 40fps, and nothing I've tried seems to improve the framerate.

To keep things simple I set up opengl with:

```
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
```

Set up of the opengl program and drawing is handled by the following class:

```
class GLRectangle {
private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "precision lowp float;" +
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform lowp mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +

        "attribute lowp vec4 vPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
        // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
        "  gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix;" +
        "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision lowp float;" +
        "uniform lowp vec4 vColor;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
        "}";

protected static int mProgram = 0;

private static ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
private static short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};//, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7 }; // order to draw vertices

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
private static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
private static final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // bytes per vertex



GLRectangle(){

    int vertexShader = GameRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = GameRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables

    // initialize byte buffer for the index list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
            drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);  
}

protected static void Draw(Drawable dObj, float mvpMatrix[])
{   
    FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = dObj.vertexBuffer;

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    //GameRenderer.checkGlError("glUseProgram");

    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    int mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
    //GameRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    int mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    //GameRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    //GameRenderer.checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    //GameRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    // Set color for drawing the quad
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, dObj.color, 0);
    //GameRenderer.checkGlError("glUniform4fv");

    // Enable a handle to the square vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    //GameRenderer.checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");

     // Prepare the square coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                    vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
    //GameRenderer.checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");

    // Draw the square
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
                              GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
    //GameRenderer.checkGlError("glDrawElements");

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    //GameRenderer.checkGlError("glDisableVertexAttribArray");
}
}
```

I've done plenty of profiling and googling, but cant find anything to make this work faster...  I've included a screenshot of the DDMS output:

[image: DDMS Output]

To me, it looks like glClear is causeing GLThread to sleep for 23ms... though I doubt that's really the case.

I have absolutely no idea how I can make this more efficient, there's nothing fancy going on. In my quest for better rendering performance I have switched to the multi-threaded approach I described, turned off alpha blending and depth testing, changed to a batched drawing approach (not applicable for this simple example), and switched everything to lowp in the shaders.

Any assistance with getting this to 60fps would be greatly appreciated!

Bruce

**edit** Well talk about overthinking a problem. It turns out that I've had the powersaving mode switched on for the past week... it seems to lock rendering to 40fps.

Comment: This sounds like just a limitation of your device, some manufacturers cap the device framerate to save power (my Atrix is capped at 30fps). 40fps should be plenty fast I think, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Sorry wasn't sure where the best place for it would be... My device is a Galaxy S3, so im hoping it can do a bit better then 40fps

Comment: You can see the difference when the quad is moving with speed, which it is required to do.

Comment: What is your Android version on the S3?

Comment: Its on android version 4.1.1, on a stock samsung firmware.

Comment: Well talk about overthinking a problem. It turns out that I've had the powersaving mode switched on for the past week... it seems to lock rendering to 40fps.

Comment: @BruceJones If you believe you've found a final cause of your issue, please answer to your own question and accept your answer.

Comment: A note on optimization. If you don't need to paint the back of you object then the right way to use culling is next:
 
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE); GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior occurs when Power Saving mode is switched on, using a Galaxy S3.

It appears the power saving mode locks the framerate to 40fps. Switching it off easily achieved the desired 60fps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have control over the EGL setup to the device surface, but if you can there is a way to set the update to run in "non-sync" mode.

```
egl.eglSwapInterval( dpy, 0 )
```

This isn't available on all devices but allows some control of your rendering.